# Are there active discussion groups about politics in Esperanto?

Tags: resources

Places where people debate, not just post links.

Comment: Questions like this, where there are a significant number of possible answers, tend to not work well on Stack Exchange sites.  They are usually considered "too broad," because they are hard or impossible to answer comprehensively.  This sort of question is common on forums, but the Q&A model that SE uses is a bit different.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Do we need to remove tags from closed questions? (Maybe this is a tag-technical issue?)

Comment: @CharlotteSL If it is a not needed tag, yes.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to check out this group on Telegram:

*Religio, politiko kaj aliaj tiklaj temoj - por paroli pri tiaj tiklaj temoj*
https://telegram.me/joinchat/APGe_D2HlCk-Yt40zprJ9g

Answer (score 4):

There's the [vidpunktoj](http://lernu.net/eo/forumo/1) forum on lernu.net. There are sometimes debates on politics, but they can get quite boring because it's the same people discussing the same stuff over and over again. Especially the debates on religion I recommend *not* to read :)